# xml-conduit: How can I get only the first tbody and only direct child trs of that tbody?

Tags: haskell, html-parsing, xml-conduit

I am using xml-conduit and Text.XML.Cursor to navigate some terrible html with nested tables. There is a table with two tbody tags and I want the immediate child tr tags of the first tbody. Here is my code so far:

```
getIdentityTableBody :: Cursor -> [Cursor]
getIdentityTableBody
  = element "table" >=> hasAttribute "summary" >=>
      attributeIs "summary" "Issuer Identity Information"
      &// element "tbody" >=> child >=> element "tr"
```

But this gets all the descendant trs of both tbody tags. I simply don't know how to get the first tbody alone, and am confused about filtering only for immediate children in that tbody.

Here is the html I am trying to parse.

```
<table summary="Issuer Identity Information" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="33%" class="FormText">CIK (Filer ID Number)</th>
      <th width="10%" class="FormText">Previous Names</th>
      <td width="23%">
        <table border="0" summary="Table with single CheckBox">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td class="CheckBox"><span class="FormData">X</span></td>
            <td align="left" class="FormText">None</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </td>
      <th width="33%" class="FormText">Entity Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001614286">0001614286</a>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="5" colspan="2" valign="top"></td>
      <td rowspan="7" valign="top">
        <table width="100%" border="0" summary="Table with Multiple boxes">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td class="CheckBox">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="FormText">Corporation</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CheckBox"><span class="FormData">X</span></td>
            <td class="FormText">Limited Partnership</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CheckBox">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="FormText">Limited Liability Company</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CheckBox">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="FormText">General Partnership</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CheckBox">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="FormText">Business Trust</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="CheckBox">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="FormText">Other (Specify)</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="FormText">Name of Issuer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="FormData">SRA US Equity Fund, LP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="FormText">Jurisdiction of Incorporation/Organization</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="FormData">DELAWARE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="FormText" colspan="2">Year of Incorporation/Organization</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table border="0" summary="Year of Incorporation/Organization">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="CheckBox">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="FormText">Over Five Years Ago</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="CheckBox"><span class="FormData">X</span></td>
              <td class="FormText">Within Last Five Years (Specify Year)</td>
              <td><span class="FormData">2014</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="CheckBox">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="FormText">Yet to Be Formed</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `&// element "tbody"` says "find every single tbody descendant", including tbody tags that are inside other tbody tags. What about using `&/` instead, which gets just the direct `tbody` descendants of the `table` element?

Two other comments:

1. If you could provide some sample XML/HTML, that would be helpful.
2. You don't need both `hasAttribute` and `attributeIs`. Just confirming that the attribute has the given value will also check that it exists.

Comment: I have added the html I am trying to parse, and you have already helped me to understand why I am getting two tbody tags in my results.